# Compile generated files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Does Visual Studio have some options to add/compile all selected files that were auto generated outside visual studio i.e in pre build event? How to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you can auto generate them once,  add then to the project and just compile...
the pre build will generate them and then you will compile with the fresh files.